# Storing user previous data in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm developing an application with the front-end written in angular and the API written in springboot. I want to store user data so they can continue next time they log in. E.g: form data, filter data, menu options...
I wrote a service to save the data every time the user change the data, e.g: when they click submit or change the menu options, and I send those data to the api at `ngOndestroy` as a json string. But it's to be a heavy job both front end and back end as the json string is too long. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If user is on browser then you can advantage of In Momory Cache by implementing the service class for cache. But as you said you want to store the information for next time login than you can encrypt the content and keep in cookie and session storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is to store the data in the database. So that your application can retrieve the data from database, when use login again next time

Comment: That's exactly What I'm doing now. The database has a field to store that json string. I'm trying to make SQL server parse and give a result as what I expect to make the json string shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep data in [locale storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage). That way data will be kept until erased from there.